Deal with large Geojson file in leaflet
Does anyone have any idea how to render a large number of polygons on an interactive map in a short amount of time? To be more specific, I'm using the "leaflet" R package to have an interactive map as a base, to which I want to add a layer composed of the outlines of French municipalities (around 40000 polygons). The municipalities need to be colored "on the fly" according to certain parameters, so if I change these parameters, it is possible that the municipalities will need to be recolored on the spot with different colors.
I read online that a method to lighten this work is to simplify the shapes of the polygons, so I followed the method explained here (Section "Comment ont été générés ces fichiers?"), which allowed me to start with a heavy .shp file and ending up with a ligheter geojson file.
However, the process of drawing all these polygons “on the fly” still takes about twenty seconds, which ruins the whole interactive experience.
Since the outlines of the municipalities, once drawn, must not change, I was wondering if there was a way to save their shape, so that they only need to be drawn once, and colored more quickly in case of changes. Or if there was a faster method for the entire process.

Did you check https://github.com/r-spatial/leafgl?

If you give each polygon a class using  options = pathOptions(className =..., then you can recolour them using javascript which avoids redrawing the polygons each time. Unfortunately I can't see an equivalent method in leafgl::addGlPolygons to give them classes. Here's an example:
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  actionButton("change_color", "Change Polygon Color"),

)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Create a polygon using sf
  polygon_sf <- st_sf(geometry = c(st_sfc(st_polygon(list(rbind(
    c(-0.08, 51.509),
    c(-0.06, 51.503),
    c(-0.047, 51.51),
    c(-0.08, 51.509)
  )))),
  st_sfc(st_polygon(list(rbind(
    c(-0.18, 51.509),
    c(-0.16, 51.503),
    c(-0.147, 51.51),
    c(-0.18, 51.509)
  ))))
  ))

  # Render the leaflet map
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng = -0.09, lat = 51.505, zoom = 13) %>%

      addPolygons(data = polygon_sf,
                  options = pathOptions(className = c("poly1", "poly2")),
                  color = "blue",
                  fillColor = "blue",
                  fillOpacity = 0.5)
  })

  observeEvent(input$change_color, {
    runjs("
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('poly1');
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].setAttribute('fill', 'red');
      }")
  })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

